# WebAPI2 attribute based routing 404 with nested route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I know there are lots of (answered) questions relating to attribute-based routing, but I can't seem to find one which answers my particular scenario.

I've got a WebAPI 2 controller, with a few methods using the default routing:

```
public Dictionary<int, SensorModel> Get()
{
    return SensorModel.List();
}

public SensorModel Get(int id)
{
    return SensorModel.Get(id);
}

[HttpPost]
public SensorModel Post(SensorModel model)
{
    if (model == null) throw new Exception("model cannot be null");
    if (model.Id <= 0) throw new Exception("Id must be set");
    return SensorModel.Update(model.Id, model);
}
```

These all work fine. I'm trying to create a nested route as below:

```
[Route("sensor/{id}/suspend")]
public SensorModel Suspend(int id, DateTime restartAt, EnSite site)
{
    return SensorModel.Suspend(id, restartAt, site);
}
```

For which I would expect the URL to look like:

```
http://[application_root]/api/sensor/1/suspend?restartAt={someDateTime}&site={anInt}
```

Sorry, forgot to say that the actual issue is a 404!
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I know that I can do it like this:

```
[Route("sensor/suspend")]
public SensorModel Suspend(int id, DateTime restartAt, EnSite site)
{
    return SensorModel.Suspend(id, restartAt, site);
}
```

Which makes the URL:

```
http://[application_root]/api/sensor/suspend?id=1&restartAt={someDateTime}&site={anInt}
```

But a cleaner API design seems to be a nested route, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong in this point:

```
For which I would expect the URL to look like:

http://[application_root]/api/sensor/1/suspend?restartAt={someDateTime}&site={anInt}
```

It should be something like below:

```
http://[application_root]/sensor/1/suspend?id=1&restartAt={someDateTime}&site={anInt}
```

When you specify an attribute based routing, it overrides the default routing architecture of `../api/..` (or whatever you specify in **route.config** file).

So, whenever you try to use **attribute based routing**, you should do something like `/route_prefix_at_controller_level/route_prefix_at_method_level`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense that if I lose the leading "/api" it shoudl work - but the route still isn't properly nested if I have to include the "id" parameter in the query string, what I'd like is for it to be pulled from earlier in the URL, as things like angular-ui-router do - any ideas?

Comment: @JamieS: I Believe, you are looking in to kind of like this: `[Route("sensor/suspend/{id}/{someDateTime}/{int}")]`. Modify your routes like this and beware: **Only when every thing (id, datetime, int) is present, this route will be matched. All fields are compulsary.**

Comment: Ah okay, so there's no way with WebAPI routing to have the pattern be "sensor/{id}/suspend/{someDateTime}/{int}" ?

Comment: @JamieS: I meant **it is valid to do so & it is perfectly possible**, but all the items `[id, someDateTime, int]` must be supplied in the Url.

Comment: that's fine, just to confirm, as my URL and yours are different: the parameters don't have to all be at the end of the URL, the "id" one can be in between 2 other elements as I have it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that :)